# Error in cypress"Constructor is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am experiencing the "Constructor is not a constructor" error on Cypress version 9.3.1. It appears when I identify a button and try to click on it.
Error "TypeError Timed out retrying after 4050ms: Constructor is not a constructor"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXWiI.png)

the error appears when determining through cy.get and cy.xpath

```
cy.get('#clr-tab-link-8').should('be.visible').click();
cy.xpath('//*[@id="clr-tab-link-8"]').should('be.visible').click();
```

Html code

```
<button _ngcontent-xqo-c23="" clrtablink="" role="tab" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="tid-app-folder-vms btn btn-link nav-link" aria-hidden="false" id="clr-tab-link-8" aria-selected="false">VMs</button>
```

the option of using `.click({ force: true });`  did not help

Answer (score 0):

I get those errors sometimes and with a retry, at the second attempt, they don't longer reproduce. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries